How would combat with war beasts but no cavalry look?
The setting I have in progress lacks horses and horse analogs (with the exception of reindeer, but they are a limited resource), but has many larger beasts capable of being tamed, i.e. war elephants, bison, and the like. The few civilizations that used war elephants in our own history almost always used them in tandem with cavalry. I imagine chariots and war elephants standing off against entrenched infantry or pike squares, both supported by extensive ranged troops. The setting itself is roughly the technology level of a post-Roman 500s/600s AD western or Middle Eastern society. I would appreciate any feedback on the idea.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you see that comment from the automated Community BOT it means your question is violating basic good question heuristics. In your case, this question is too broad (violating the [help/dont-ask]'s Book Rule) and failing to focus on a single problem. You don't focus on just one creature in just one circumstance that is well defined both from the attacker and defender perspective. VTC Needs More Focus. Please carefully read the [tour] and the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].

Your question says there both is and isn't cavalry, please clarify.

@ash he is basically describing Roman Republic warfare where there were enough horsemen to function as scouts and such, but not enough to form up a proper battlefield cavalry force.  In 500-600AD some armies were as much as a 1:1 ratio of infantry and cavalry, but in 200BC the ratio would have been more like 60:1.

do you have draft animals, becasue thats a much bigger deal than calvary?

@Nosajimiki That would be a much more helpful description, as written the question is self-contradictory.

@Ash Actually, re-reading this question, it is full of self contradictions.  Pike squares and Chariots were both considered obsolete in the early medieval period.  Most Europeans still fought using the techniques and technologies of the late Roman Empire.  I think more than anything, the OP needs to specify if he wants 500-600AD technology or armies made of chariots and pike blocks.

They would be used exactly like historical war elephants
Yes, the same armies that used war elephants also used cavalry, but they were used to support the infantry, not the cavalry.  Take Carthage for example.  They placed thier war elephants in the front line of thier infantry to break enemy infantry formations allowing thier own infantry to move in and clean up the enemy's broken ranks while thier cavalry was used for flanking, skirmishing, and pushing routes.  None of these are ideal roles for war elephants or other such large beasts.
These warbeasts don't replace cavalry; so, you should not try to make them.  Plenty of armies in antiquity had very few cavalry, and did just fine; so, as long as the enemy also does not have cavalry, you should look at phalanx or maniple style warfare as your civilization's primary military doctrine.

Until those tactics lose thier effectiveness
Following the fall of Carthage, military tactics for isolating and killing war elephants became effective enough that they simply fell out of use.  However, it was the high quality of Roman training and tactics that ended the age of war-elephants, not a technological advancement.
The Roman strategy required to beat War Elephants was a carefully choreographed maneuver that required the army to march in a specific formation, and for every soldier in that formation to know exactly where they needed to go and when as the elephant approached.  This level of training is not a technology but a specific aspect of Rome's military doctrine.
In our own history, by 500-600AD most armies reverted to non-professional levees, and had cavalry not become the new META, war-elephant tactics could have seen a resurgence in usefulness against the increasingly untrained armies of the early medieval period.
What if your opponent follows Roman training and doctrine?
The Roman tactic to zipper thier battle lines around the elephant and kill it from the less armored sides is only effective against a loose formation of elephants.  Historically speaking, most armies that used them only had enough elephants that they had to space them out about 1 every 15-60 meters to cover thier front line.  If you have war elephants and expect the enemy to zipper, then you need to pull your elephants together into a  solid line.  A tighter formation of elephants will not allow the enemy  enough space to zipper, but will not give your army enough coverage for the elephants to make a difference on a battlefield wide scale... at least not directly.
If a solid force of war elephants is used to break through a specific point in the enemy line, you can force them to roll or thier line which gives you a bit of a concentration of force advantage, or if you get lucky, it can trigger a route which can cascade across the whole enemy battle formation.

And then look into how Rome dealt with those elephants.  The tactics were reportedly quite effective.

@Mark Those tactics only worked because Hannibal already lost so many war elephants by the Battle of Zama that he needed to spread his elephants out very thin (not like in the picture shown above).  This gave the Romans the ability to maneuver around them, but if you pack them close enough together, then that strategy won't work

Zama was hardly the only battle where the Romans beat elephants.  Look at Magnesia, or Thapsus, or Ilipa, or Thermopylae (the one in 191 BC), or just about any other battle after 250 BC where the Romans faced elephants.

In all of those battles, the enemy had about 1 elephant per 1000-2000 men which means the enemy was even more elephant scarce than Hannibal at Zama where he had 1 per 500 men.  It does raise the question though about if such beasts can be domesticated in sufficient quantity to overcome Scipio's tactics.  A tight enough of a formation of war elephants leading a phalanx would probably required to beat scipio's tactics would a ratio closer to 30-60 to 1, so, if you expect scipio's tactics to be used, isolating war elephants to select parts of the front-line may be a better use of them than spread

I don't think you can get enough elephants to do the job.  An elephant requires roughly the same logistic support as 30 cavalry or 150 infantry, so an army not following a river can support a maximum of about 250 elephants.

More Pikes
So, your world does not have horses, but has some animals larger than a horse more trainable (as trainable as a horse?). First, very large animals are not going to be the backbone of armies even if they are more trainable than in our world. Large animals such as elephants need to eat a lot of food. This by itself will limit the number of them you can have in your army, because your soldies need to eat as well. Even in ancient/medieval warfare when armies had a much greater ability to live off the land than they do now, logistical issues, especially the ability to feed your army, often played a decisive role in the outcome of conflicts.
Also, one reason why horses were so common in armies was that they weren't just there for warfare. Humans domesticated horses for economic reasons, same as cattle, sheep and other domestic animals. There were a lot of horses to be used for warfare because a lot of people were breeding them for other uses. The reason steppe nomads could field devastating all-cavalry armies was because the livelyhood of pretty much every family relied on breeding horses.
You can't replace horses' place in economy with very large animals like elephants or hippos or rhinos or whatever simply because no matter how much labor they can provide, most people won't be able to feed them. So you will have the same situation as with war elephants in antiquity - only a very small number of those animals will ever be able to be trained and kept in an army. They will be used in similar ways to war elephants - as shock troops to break formations. You could start off with a war rhino charge to breach a crucial part of the enemy formation, or go after the the enemy king, and then the rest of the army would follow up. The tactics used against them will probably be similar to what Romans used irl - focusing on getting out of the way of these creatures and trying to cause them to panic and run amok.
So why is my answer not 'same as historical ancient/medieval combat'? I think bisons could make a difference. I believe more trainable bisons could, maybe not replace horses exactly, but to be extensively domesticated. After all, very similar yaks have been extensively domesticated in parts of East Asia. So unlike elephants, hippos, rhinos and such, which you would only see in extremely small numbers, a lot of armies would have bison cavalry (bisonry?). Now, a bison is not a very agile animal, at least not as agile as a horse, so you probably couldn't have bison archers. Their main use would be as heavy cavalry, relying on power of their charge. Even horses in real medieval warfare ended up mainly used for this purpose. Now, a bison charge I imagine would be pretty powerful. To defend against it, you'd use the same tactics you'd use against heavy cavalry - pikes and maybe static defenses, like spikes, ditches and so on.
